# Distribution of multivariate uniform random variable in R

Tags: r, random, uniform-distribution

I have `k>2`uniform independent random variables with different `upper` and `lower`
for example: `X~U[-1,1], Y~U[0,1],Z~U[-1,0]` and so on.

I have to calculate for a RV given by `RV=X+Y+Z` the probability that it is greater than some scalar `x` for example:`x=0.2` and I have to calculate `Pr(RV>x)`. Is there any easier way I can calculate using `R`. I have an array of `>1000` random variables and I need to calculate this for each possible combinations of these variables. Therefore I am trying to avoid sampling route.

Comment: This may fit better to math.SE. Maybe [this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0411298v1.pdf) will help you, found in a comment in a [math.SE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370228/probability-distribution-of-a-sum-of-uniform-random-variables)

Comment: I don't think R will be very useful for calculating this here. You can calculate this in closed form as the convolution of the densities of your variables - see [here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~susan/courses/s116/node114.html) for 2 variables (just do it again for the third). R could only help you to simulate this to get an approximate answer.

Comment: @HolgerHoefling, Thanks for your comment. Is there a neat way I use R for approximate answer ?

Comment: @MartinNyolt thanks a lot for sharing the document. I would try to use it. Let me know if you have any suggestion on applying a neat way to use `R` to get approximate answers. Thanks!

Comment: @vivek The easiest way is of course to simulate it. Draw lets say 1 million random samples for each your X, Y and Z vectors>. I would draw them as U[0,1] using the unif function. You can easily transform them to U[lower, upper] as (U[0,1] * (upper - lower) ) + lower. Then just sum the so transformed X, Y and Z and calculate your probabilities from this. So, essentially this is just the sampling route you were trying to avoid ...